# How to use the textbox value to fetch the records and to display it in the same page

Tags: javascript

i am having a Form like

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     function formfn()
  {
   var str = document.getElementById('TitleSearch').value;
  alert(str);//displays the keyword like database
   }

   </script>






  <form name="f1" method="post">
   <p><label for="TitleSearch">Keywords:</label> 
   <input title="Keyword" size="40" value="" id="TitleSearch"></p> 
   <p>
   <input type="submit" id="im-search" value="Search" name="im-search" onClick="formfn();"></p>
      </form>
```

I am having a page where in the top i have this form on search it has to take the value of the textbox TitleSearch and to use this to retrieve the records matching by

```
      <?php
$db         =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_Publications where keyword like "%valueretrieved%" ';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
      //echo $rows;
      ?>
```

Once the search button is clicked the text box value of the keyword is retrieved .
I am trying to use this value in the select query to fetch the records and to display in the same page..

How to do so..

Answer (score 0):

Pls change the button type

Here is the modified code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function formfn()
 {
   var str = document.getElementById('TitleSearch').value;
   alert(str);
 }
</script>

<form name="f1" method="post">
   <p><label for="TitleSearch">Keywords:</label> 
     <input title="Keyword" size="40" value="" id="TitleSearch" 
      name="TitleSearch"></p> 
      <p> <input type="button" id="im-search" value="Search" name="im-search" 
       onClick="formfn();"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into AJAX

Here is the simple version from w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

alternative is jQuery:
The first of the links here can get you to the next step - google for
 ***php ajax jQuery***

Answer (score 0):

This is AJAX database.
See
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp
which gives a really specific details. You need a separate PHP page to call your DB.

I did this function before. Just make sure your PHP page is not accessible and safe enough.